# How can I add column with the dates (starting from today)?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

How can I add to column C the dates (starting from today)? Column B is an example of what I want to get.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'N': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'B': ['16.11.2021', '17.11.2021', '18.11.2021', '19.11.2021'], 'C': ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
import datetime
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = sorted([(base - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for x in range(len(df))])
df['C'] = date_list
```

This will produce the same result as in column `B`.

Comment: If more than 1 month, then everything breaks down (

Comment: ('%Y.%m.%d')  - it helps